# Why is there a difference between training and validation accuracy when both of them are pointing to the same subset?

Tags: accuracy, tensorflow, supervised-learning

I was training a model and I accidentally pointed the training and testing set to the same dataset. I was surprised by the fact the validation and training accuracy are not the same. What could be the cause of this? And, Why is the validation accuracy jumping around while the training accuracy is relatively stable?

```
train_dir = 'dataset/train'
test_dir = 'dataset/train'       #should have been dataset/val

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    seed=1337,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=16,
    color_mode='rgb',
    label_mode='categorical',
)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    seed=1337,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=16,
    color_mode='rgb',
    label_mode='categorical',
)
```

The model is VGG16 with a modified top of dense and pooling layers. It does not have dropout, batch norm, or other regularization layers that would have behaved differently in the training and testing phases.

```
model = VGG16(input_tensor=inputs,input_shape=input_shape,include_top=False)
y = model.output
y = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(y)
y = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(y)

outputs = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(y)
model =keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.summary()


Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 block1_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
                                                                 
 block1_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
                                                                 
 block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
                                                                 
 block2_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
                                                                 
 block2_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
                                                                 
 block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 block3_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
                                                                 
 block3_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
                                                                 
 block4_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
                                                                 
 block4_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
                                                                 
 block5_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 7, 7, 64)          32832     
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling2d (G  (None, 64)               0         
 lobalAveragePooling2D)                                          
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 195       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 14,747,715
Trainable params: 14,747,715
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

This the training result
[image: This is the result I got]

Comment: You're asking about the behavior of a model, but you haven't told us what the model is, or how it's trained. More to the point, does your network use dropout, batch norm, or other regularization techniques that behave differently during training and testing?

Comment: @Sycorax updated as you suggested

Comment: Thanks for doing that. We're making progress. Note that if you use the train accuracy that you get from each mini-batch as you update the weights, then the accuracy you get from the first mini-batch in an epoch will be "stale" compared to the accuracy from the last mini-batch. How are you measuring accuracy?

Comment: The training accuracy was measured using the latest updated model at the end of each epoch. I guess that is how TensorFlow calculates the accuracy by default.